# Why isn't Amaretto Kosher for Passover?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover, chametz-leaven, liquor-beer

I was recently told that Amaretto isn't Kosher for Passover (as I never drink it, I don't much care, but it got me very curious, as to the best of my knowledge there is nothing in its ingredients that would be Chametz or Kitnyot?)

Interestingly, some articles (e.g. WSJ's Passover coctails) listed Amaretto.

But [CRC's list](http://www.crcweb.org/LiquorList.pdf) does NOT have "Kosher for Passover" against Amaretto (but does against other wines).

Is Amaretto Kosher for Passover, and if not ***WHY*** specifically?

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure it depends on the specific type, and producer. The CRC list you linked contains 2 Kosher for Passover Amarettos (search for amaretto on the page), but also gives a reason for why Amarettos need passover certification:

> Liqueurs are, by definition, **flavored drinks** and require
>   certification. Sometimes a liqueur is referred to as an
>   aperitif or cordial. Some examples of liqueurs are the
>   beverages known as Alexander, **Amaretto**, Arak,
>   Curacao, Eggnog, Goldwasser, Grasshopper, and Sloe
>   Gin.

A significant number of flavoring agents are Chametz or Kitniyos, see [here](https://oukosher.org/blog/industrial-kosher/meeting-the-challenge-of-certifying-flavors-for-passover/) for an OU article on flavorings.

Comment: I don't know the precise process, but there are many spirits that are made by mixing alcohol with flavours. Especially in Europe this alcohol is produced from grains, which is chametz. The same reason applies for vinegar, since it is usually made from alcohol (except for wine producing countries).
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectified_spirit

Comment: Yes but which specific flavoring agents in Amaretto are Chametz or Kitniyos?

Comment: @DD1 I don't know [the secret ingredients](http://www.disaronno.com/en/heritage) from here. It could be anything

Comment: @DD1 [I suppose the bigger problem is the alcohol, not the flavouring...]

Answer (score 0):

Some alcoholic beverages are aged in casks to absorb the flavoring of the desired wood. Many are aged in multiple types of casks which is considered unclean due to cross contamination from one cask to another.

Comment: It's a general kashrut concern, not a pesach related one...

Comment: @Kazibácsi correct.  Also, Ephraim, it would greatly increase the credibility of your answer if you were to provide sources.